# How do you make the Web Frontend SQL Server Mirror Aware?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, mirroring

I'm in the process of mirroring the SQL Server back-ends, but I've had a helluva time trying to find the code/procedure for making the web front-end (SP 2013) aware of the SQL Mirroring.

I've recently been handed SharePoint for administration, so I'm pretty much a total new when it comes to SharePoint.  Thanks in advance for any help or direction you can provide.

Comment: What is your current configuration, how you connected with your SQL server from SharePoint( via ALias or server name)? are you going to mirroring or Always-ON?

Comment: We've connected via the server name and it is mirroring, no AO/AG.

Comment: after configuring mirroring, will you create an alias which will point to Mirror or something else...i am little behind on mirror so that's why i asked

Comment: I thought there was a way to configure the WFE through PowerShell or the Central Admin to be aware of both the SQL Servers and the databases that are in the mirrored pair?

Answer (score 2):

In order to tell sharepoint mirroring, you have to create an alias on the server.

- Use "C:\Windows\System32\cliconfg.exe" (on all servers in the farm
- Create an alias with the same name as you are using in the SharePoint( server name) and point it your Mirroring servers.

[Check this one for more info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2012/08/06/install-configure-sharepoint-2013-with-sql-client-alias/) or [use this one](http://smallcitydesign.com/configure-sql-client-aliases/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following after changing my search string in Google for the 7th time!

[Make SharePoint Mirroring Aware](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1084804/Make-SharePoint-Mirroring-Aware)

@Waqas - Do I still need to create the alias you listed after performing the steps in the aforementioned link?